# Autoit PixelGetColor not working

Tags: windows-8, autoit

Hello there everyone,

I have recently downloaded a bot for a game that I play, this bot uses Autoit to automate movements on screen, alongside Autoit I downloaded some scripts that allow me to automate in-game movements. I downloaded these scripts on my main pc and my laptop so I can run them on 2 accounts if need be. The download is exactly the same and although the bot works perfectly on my PC, it does something weird on my laptop:

The cursor seems to be able to go to places I have specificly told it to go but once it needs to imagesearch or pixelsearch it simply stops. The program doesnt stop running and will continue performing the actions that it can perform, at the right timing, however all imagesearching functions get left out.

The only major diference between the pc and laptop is that the laptop is running windows 8.

**Things Iv tried by searching prior to asking here:**

I have read that imagesearch.dll should be in sysWOW64 in order for it to work and I beleive I have done that by copying the DLL files and pasting them in syswow64. That did not help.

I also tried adding #requireadmin to the top of the script which did not help either.

this is happening with ALL the scripts I downloaded. They all work on pc and none work on laptop. I dont have alot of understanding with this code as I did not write it myself. However I have familirized myself with it a little as I do edit it for my personal uses on my pc and make it work very well. So I thought that it not functioning on my laptop must be some amateur mistake about windows 8 or similar.

here is an example script.

```
 #RequireAdmin
 #include <Misc.au3>

HotKeySet("{[}", "MakeLock")
HotKeySet("{z}", "Start")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "_Exit")
HotKeySet("{x}", "Shafts")
HotKeySet("{c}", "Heads")
HotKeySet("{v}", "bsb")
$handle = WinGetHandle("Wurm Online", "")

Global $running=0
Global $shaftLoc
 Global $headLoc
Global $shaft=0
  Global $head=0
  Global $bsb=0
  Global $bsbloc

Func _Exit()
Exit
EndFunc   ;==>_Exit

Func Getfrombsb()
                      MouseMove($bsbloc[0], $bsbloc[1], 5)
                    MouseDown("left")
                    Sleep(100)
                          MouseMove($shaftloc[0], $shaftloc[1], 5)
                          Sleep(100)
                          MouseUp("left")
                          sleep(2500)
                          send ("4")
                          sleep(250)
                               Send("{Enter}")
                               sleep(3000)
                               EndFunc


Func Shafts()
   MsgBox(0, "", "title of items")
   $shaft=1
EndFunc

    Func Drop()
                           MouseMove($shaftloc[0], $shaftloc[1], 5)
                    MouseDown("left")
                    Sleep(250)
                    MouseMove($bsbloc[0], $bsbloc[1], 5)
                    MouseUp("left")
                 EndFunc

Func bsb()
          MsgBox(0, "", "item in bsb")
     $bsb=1
  EndFunc

    Func Heads()
   MsgBox(0, "", "Click on what ur continuing")
   $head=1
EndFunc

Func continue()
  MouseMove($shaftloc[0], $shaftloc[1], 5)
  MouseClick("left")
  Sleep(100)
  MouseMove($shaftloc[0], $shaftloc[1], 5)
  MouseClick("right")
Sleep(1000)
$line = GetLine()
If IsArray($line) Then
   Local $random2 = Random(200, 250, 1)
      MouseMove($line[0], $line[1]+3*16-8, 5)
      Sleep($random2-51)
      MouseMove($line[0]+120, $line[1]+3*16-8, 5)
      Sleep($random2+38)
      MouseMove($line[0]+120, $line[1]+3*16-8+2*16, 5)
      Sleep(500)
      MouseMove($line[0]+200, $line[1]+3*16-8+2*16, 5)
      Sleep($random2+161)
      MouseMove($line[0]+200, $line[1]+3*16-8+2*16+44, 25)
      Sleep($random2)
                MouseClick("left")
EndIf

 EndFunc


 Func Start()
   if $running==0 Then
          $running=1
          TrayTip("", "Macro started", 5)
   ElseIf $running==1 Then
          $running=0
          TrayTip("", "Macro stopped", 5)
   EndIf
 EndFunc

 Func GetLine()
   $pos = MouseGetPos()
   $samp = $pos
   For $i = 0 To 48 Step 1
          $samp[0] = $pos[0]+32
          $samp[1] = $pos[1]+$i
          $s0 = PixelGetColor($samp[0], $samp[1], $handle)
          If $s0 == 0xFFFFFF Then
                 $s1 = PixelGetColor($samp[0]+1, $samp[1], $handle)
                 If $s1 == 0xFFFFFF Then
                        $s2 = PixelGetColor($samp[0]+2, $samp[1], $handle)
                        $s3 = PixelGetColor($samp[0]+3, $samp[1], $handle)
                        If $s2 == 0xFFFFFF AND $s3 == 0xFFFFFF Then
                        $line = $samp
                        ExitLoop
                 EndIf
                 EndIf
          EndIf
          $line = 0
   Next
   Return $line
 EndFunc

 While (1)
   if _IsPressed("01") And $shaft==1 Then
          $shaftloc = MouseGetPos()
          $shaft=0
          MsgBox(0, "", "shaft loc loaded")
          endif
                 if _IsPressed("01") And $head==1 Then
          $headloc = MouseGetPos()
          $head=0
          MsgBox(0, "", "head loc loaded")
       EndIf
                         if _IsPressed("01") And $bsb==1 Then
          $bsbloc = MouseGetPos()
          $bsb=0
          MsgBox(0, "", "bsb loc loaded")
   EndIf
   if $running==1 Then
        Getfrombsb()
      Local $random = Random(24000, 25000, 1)
        continue()
          Sleep($random)
        sleep(500)
        Drop()
        sleep(2000)
        Drop()
        sleep(2000)



   EndIf
   Sleep(10)
  WEnd
```

---

After watching exactly what it does and does not do, I can see that problem arrises with the section of code below it does everything up until; $line = GetLine()

```
$line = GetLine()
If IsArray($line) Then
   Local $random2 = Random(200, 250, 1)
      MouseMove($line[0], $line[1]+3*16-8, 5)
      Sleep($random2-51)
      MouseMove($line[0]+120, $line[1]+3*16-8, 5)
      Sleep($random2+38)
      MouseMove($line[0]+120, $line[1]+3*16-8+2*16, 5)
      Sleep(500)
      MouseMove($line[0]+200, $line[1]+3*16-8+2*16, 5)
      Sleep($random2+161)
      MouseMove($line[0]+200, $line[1]+3*16-8+2*16+44, 25)
      Sleep($random2)
                MouseClick("left")
EndIf

EndFunc
```

Any help would be appreciated. And although I am not familiar with code that much I do know how to use stack overflow well as my brother is a .net developer. I will mark the question that helps me and upvote and such.

Kind regards.

Comment: what is the output of $line = GetLine()? what odes $line have?

Comment: It it getting a line in a pop-up box, but nothing happens, the cursor wont move to the corect spot on the image.

Comment: Tried it on another laptop, running windows 7 seems to work as well. However I did notice that if I change the resolution of the game or the graphics setting too much it stops working in exactly the same way as well. However I have been unable to pinpoint which funtion it is that stops it working properly.

Comment: have you tried to output $samp[0] and $samp[1], does these output the wanted position ? what about $s0 what does that output? I just want to be sure that the error is at $s0(pixel get color) sorry i ask so much but I dont have windows 8, so I have to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I know what your problem is.. I think. Try turning the output of PixelGetColor() into Hex.
Also, when it outputs, it doesnt include the "0x" at the beginning of the color tag.
So, you could say:

```
#Include <Misc.au3> ;for the _ispressed() function

Do
Until _IsPressed("01") ;wait for click
$mouse = MouseGetPos() ;Get cursor info

$color = Hex(PixelGetColor($mouse[0], $mouse[1]), 6) Get info on the pixel under the mouse.
;Lets just say the color is white
If $color == "FFFFFF" Then
    MsgBox(0, "Success", "Colors match!")
EndIf
```

As for the ImageSearch not working, that could be a problem with AutoHotKey's compatability with Windows 8. Because of AutoIt not having a ImageSearch function, developers use AutoHotKey's ImageSearch function, and wrap it up in an AutoIt library. That may be where the problem is cominh